# Why won't Ubuntu recognise that my monitor has changed?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, samsung

I use 2 external monitors in addition to my built-in laptop monitor. I recently replaced one of the external monitors (previously had 1 old Samsung 22" and one new Samsung 32" 4k, now have 2 new Samsung 32" 4k), but display settings has not updated to reflect this. The new 32" monitor only has the resolution options that were correct for the old 22" monitor, and when you select it on the drop-down menu it is listed as Samsung 22". How do I get Ubuntu to forget the old monitor and correctly set up the new one? Using Ubuntu 20.04

EDIT: I have tried restarting, deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml and doing both together, but without success.

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: 2x 4K displays probably exceeds the bandwidth that your laptop GPU or ports are capable of.  Most laptops only support the native display +1

Comment: Is there any way of checking the bandwidth of my GPU and/or ports @Nmath? And shouldn't the monitor still be listed correctly but maybe with higher resolutions unavailable?